# None value returned

Tags: python

The code below is used in a function:

```
def print_query(x):
    h = open('/home/rv/data.txt', 'r')
    read = h.readlines()
    for line in read:
        return line
```

When the value "line" is retunred it should print but instead i get the value "None"

Comment: print_query doesn't actually print anything. And that is the least of this code's problems.

Comment: Your return statement will be reached once, which means the first line in the "read" list of lines will be returned and the others will be lost.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
with open('/home/rv/data.txt','r') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        print line
```

If you're on Python 2.5 you might need a `from __future__ import with_statement` on top.

Also: why do you `return` the line when you want to `print` it?

Comment: Looks to me like you have sussed-out OP's actual intention and delivered sane Python code to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

You are not checking if the "read" variable actually contains any lines - if it does not, then the function will fall through the for loop and return None.

Using the for loop is also silly - why would you read all lines, and only return the first one, especially in a for loop? What happens when the file can't be opened?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the loop will only execute one time, but it is still a bizarre anti-pattern for getting the first line of a file. There about to be a contest to find stranger ways of doing it than this.

Comment: the file isnt empty, ah i didnt relise how would i retuen all the lines?

Comment: Do you want to return the line to the calling code or just print them?
If you want to return them, just return h.readlines()

Comment: That's because your file is empty

Comment: @Liam, the file `/home/rv/data.txt` really is empty. Make sure you are using the correct filename. Check again that it has something in it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're bothering with a loop in your function, since it's just going to return after the first iteration anyway. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It seems like there is a deeper conceptual issue here, beyond the simple implementation issues.

Answer (score 0):

When you are writing:

```
def f:
  return 1
  return 2
```

the function returns 1.

if you want to return few values you can return it in a list:

```
def f:
  ans = []
  ans.append(1)
  ans.append(2)
  return ans
```

another option is to use "yield". google it when you will ready for it

Answer (score 0):

Another problem with the function is that <strike>you're iterating over the wrong object</strike> being more verbose than you need to be. To iterate over lines in a file, just do this:

```
for line in open(file, "r"):
    print line
```

Comment: readlines() returns a list containing all the lines in the file. While it's obviously more verbose than necessary (and will use a little more memory), there's nothing "wrong" about using readlines to explicitly get the list of lines to iterate over.

Comment: readlines() and later xreadlines() were frequently used in the old days before file objects were iterable

Comment: Oh, my mistake. I'll leave this here as it's still somewhat helpful.